# Laravel 4.0 : Eager loading error - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

I'm trying to utilize the eager loading feature in laravel but it doesn't work as i expected. When i try to check the profile of user who doesn't have information in Profiles table it throws "Trying to get property of non-object" instead of giving a NULL value. I have separated users information into two tables -> users table and Profiles table. How can i get past that?!

ProfilesController.php

```
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
    class ProfilesController extends \BaseController {

    public function show($username)
{
    try {
    $user = User::with('profile')->whereUsername($username)->firstOrFail();


    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {

        return Redirect::home()->with('globalerror', 'The user you are trying to search does not exists!');

    }
    return View::make('profiles.show')->withUser($user);
}
   }
```

Profiles.php Model

```
    class Profile extends Eloquent
    {

        public function owner(){
         return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
          }
    }
```

Users.php model

```
    use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

    class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'password_temp', 'code', 'active');



    public function profile(){
    return $this->hasOne('Profile');
     }


   }
```

Answer (score 2):

That is one downfall of using the `with()` function.  It will return a user even if the user does not have a profile.

What you can do is make sure there is a profile using something like `isset($user->profile) ? $user->profile : 'user does not have a profile';`

Or you can use `has()` in place of `with()` which will only get the user if it has a profile.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
$user = User::with('profile')->whereUsername($username)->firstOrFail();
return View::make('profiles.show')->withUser($user);
```

Then in your `view`; you may try something like this:

```
@if(isset($user) && isset($user->profile))
    {{ $user->profile->propertyname or '' }}
@endif
```

Comment: Actually `it didn't work` doesn't tell anything about the problem, can you be more informative ?

Comment: i modified my view [ since the controller code is just like yours ] , and adapted your approach but i'm still having the same error just like before

Comment: Check the update and what have you used instead of `propertyname` ?

Comment: i have applied the update, and used biography [ which is a column in profiles table ] in place of propertyname

Answer (score 0):

The only way which works so far , i have decided to manually insert a user id into the profiles table whenever new user registers. This will make eager loading work without problems because it won't return null anymore. Here is the code:

```
    $profile = new Profile;
    $profile->user_id = $user->id;
    $profile->save();`
```

Hope it might help someone out there someday